# Using a case statement with a for loop in Bash scripting Linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

This script is supposed to look at my parameters and tell me if the word begins with an uppercase, lowercase, or digit. Right now when i put in a # of words it tells me that they are all uppercase. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

startwithdigit=0
startwithupper=0
startwithlower=0
startwithother=0

for digit in $@

do
case $@ in

    [[:lower:]]* ) startwithlower=$((startwithlower+1)) ;;

    [[:upper:]]* ) startwithupper=$((startwithupper+1)) ;;

    [[:digit:]]* ) startwithdigit=$((startwithdigit+1)) ;;

esac

done

echo $startwithlower words begin with a lowercase
echo $startwithupper words begin with a capital
echo $startwithdigit words begin with a digit
```

~
~

Comment: Hint: you never use `digit` in the body of the `for` loop, and `$@` has the same value in every iteration of the loop that is iterating over its value.

Comment: you can simplify the arithmetic: `((startwithlower++))` etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

I am using if statements instead of case, and i am counting by appending in file and later taking word count, instead of adding 1 each time to a counter.

```
# Sample data

"India China dubai germany 123 456 666" to the script. 

 It has 2 uppercase words, 2 lowercase words and 3 digit words.

# Sample output

bash$> ./upper_lower.sh "India China dubai germany 123 456 666"

2 words are lowercase

2 words are uppercase

3 words are digits
```

# The script.

```
bash$> cat upper_lower.sh
#!/bin/bash


# Main loop to process the words passed to script in ARGV array

for w in $@

do
        echo $w | while read word
        do

                # Matching lowercase only
                if [[ $word =~ ^[a-z] ]]
                then
                        echo $word >> aa
                fi

                # Matching UPPERCASE only
                if [[ $word =~ ^[A-Z] ]]
                then
                        echo $word >> bb
                fi

                # Matching digits only
                if [[ $word =~ ^[0-9] ]]
                then
                        echo $word >> cc
                fi

        done
done

l=`cat aa|wc -l`        # Taking lowercase count
u=`cat bb|wc -l`        # Taking uppercase count
d=`cat cc|wc -l`        # Taking digits count

echo; echo "$l words are lowercase"     # Added extra echo just to print new line.
echo; echo "$u words are uppercase"
echo; echo "$d words are digits"

rm aa bb cc             # removing temp files after processing
bash$>
```